# remove the Colon after drupal comment fields

Tags: drupal, layout

how to remove the Colon and the red star singal after drupal comment fields. (Name:,Email:*,Homepage:*).i want to remove the colon which after those (name,email,homepage filed).Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To eliminate the colon & the red 'required field' asterisk (although that introduces some usability issues perhaps) you would likely add the following to your themes template.php file and override Drupals core theme_form_element():

```
function MYTHEMENAME_form_element($element, $value) {
  // This is also used in the installer, pre-database setup.
  $t = get_t();

  $output = '<div class="form-item"';
  if (!empty($element['#id'])) {
    $output .= ' id="' . $element['#id'] . '-wrapper"';
  }
  $output .= ">\n";
  $required = !empty($element['#required']) ? '<span class="form-required" title="' . $t('This field is required.') . '"></span>' : '';

  if (!empty($element['#title'])) {
    $title = $element['#title'];
    if (!empty($element['#id'])) {
      $output .= ' <label for="' . $element['#id'] . '">' . $t('!title !required', array('!title' => filter_xss_admin($title), '!required' => $required)) . "</label>\n";
    }
    else {
      $output .= ' <label>' . $t('!title !required', array('!title' => filter_xss_admin($title), '!required' => $required)) . "</label>\n";
    }
  }

  $output .= " $value\n";

  if (!empty($element['#description'])) {
    $output .= ' <div class="description">' . $element['#description'] . "</div>\n";
  }

  $output .= "</div>\n";

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: thank you, got it. if i only want to overrite the comment form. Is there a way i can do?

Comment: [check out this article from lullabot for that approach](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/overriding-theme-functions-in-modules) it requires you to have a bit more fun and make your own module :)

Comment: also [check out how the wordpress comments module](http://drupal.org/project/wp_comments) does it: